# Azure function access from other subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-ad-b2b

I have created an ARM template for my logic app which has azure function reference in it.

By the time when I was deploying the logic app in my old subscription, I was able to deploy the ARM template using power shell successfully,

The problem started when I needed to deploy the app in different subscription.

While I deployed my logic app on different subscription which was pointing to the azure functions which still existed in my old subscription, I got this error.

```
 {
   "code": "LinkedAuthorizationFailed",
   "message": "The client has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/listSecrets/action' on scope '/subscriptions/(newsubscription Id)/resourcegroups/(new resourcegroup under new subscription)/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/my-logic-app-name', however the current tenant '(tenent id of new subscription)' is not authorized to access linked subscription '(old subscription id)'."
}
```

Can anyone suggest how can I deal with this issue?
What I suspect is the new subscription needs to get access over old subscription for accessing azure function lying in there. What can be done in this case?

Comment: This may helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60672958/what-does-the-linkedauthorizationfailed-mean-in-powershell

Comment: Why not just call the function url in your logic app instead of use the function connector in it.